# Why we cannot have $P(|X-\mathbb{E}[X]|\leq\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)}/2)=1$?

Tags: probability

Show that it is impossible to have $P(|X-m|\leq\sqrt{v}/2)=1$ for a real random variable $X$ with finite positive variance $v$ and expectation $m$.

I can give a counterexample:

$
X= \begin{cases} 2 & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{8}, \\ 0 & \text{with probability } \frac{3}{4}, \\-2 & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{8}. \end{cases}
$

Then $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$ and $\text{Var}(X)=1$, so 
$P(|X-m|\leq\sqrt{v}/2)=P(|X|\leq1/2)=P(X=0)=\frac{3}{4}\neq1$.

But how can we show it for a general $m$ and $v$? Or at least is there a better or more straightforward way to explain why we cannot have $P(|X-m|\leq\sqrt{v}/2)=1$?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Hint: If $P(|X-E(X)|\leqslant x)=1$ then var$(X)\leqslant x^2$.

Comment: @Did. I am still not very sure how does your hint relate to the question? So $\sqrt(Var(x))\leq x$, then $\frac{\sqrt(Var(x))}{2}\leq x$? Can you clarify a bit further? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you use $x=\frac12\sqrt{\text{var}(X)}$ in the hint. (Suspense...)